# javascript check if a key value exists in 2 JSON objects at once

Tags: javascript, json

I have 2 JSON objects and want to check if a value from the first one appears anywhere in the second one, and if it does, push it into an array. I've tried to write a for loop to do this, but somehow I can't seem to get it right.

Can anybody point out what I'm doing wrong?

```js
var JSON1 = [{
    "1": "1",
        "2": "2"
}, {
    "1": "3",
        "2": "4"
}];

var JSON2 = [{
    "1": "1",
        "2": "2"
}, {
    "1": "3",
        "2": "4"
}];

var matching = [];

for (var key in JSON1) {
    if(JSON2[.hasOwnProperty(JSON1[key].1) ) {
  matching.push(JSON1[key].1);
 }
}

console.log(matching);
```

Comment: Could you show us some sample input and output

Comment: You could just compare the keys: [`Object.keys(some_obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). Btw. The question "Can anybody point out what I'm doing wrong?" is quite ironic given the vast amount of syntax errors in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: For numbers as key you should use `obj[number]` not `obj.number`.

```js
var JSON1 = [{
    "1": "1",
        "2": "2"
}, {
    "1": "3",
        "2": "4"
}];

var JSON2 = [{
    "1": "1",
        "2": "2"
}, {
    "1": "3",
        "2": "4"
}];

var matching = [];

for (var key in JSON1) {
    for(var k in JSON1[key]){
        if(key in JSON2 && k in JSON2[key] && JSON1[key][k] == JSON2[key][k]) {
            matching.push(JSON1[key][k]);
        }
    }
}

console.log(matching);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can compare both by there values

```
var JSON1 = [{
    "1": "1",
        "2": "2"
}, {
    "1": "3",
        "2": "4"
}];

var JSON2 = [{
    "1": "1",
        "2": "2"
}, {
    "1": "3",
        "2": "4"
}];

var matching = [];



for(x in JSON1) {
  for(y in JSON1[x]){
    if(JSON1[x][y] ==  JSON2[x][y]){
       matching.push(JSON1[x][y]);
       }
  }
}



console.log(matching);
```